# awk replace multiline, delete Nth occurrence

Tags: awk, replace, multiline

I'm trying to use awk to replace a multiple string in a file. I have a repeated set of lines that I need to replace and delete. For example the file has

```
INSTANCE "INVX1":"physical"
"A" : "reset"
"Y" : "pp_resetbar"

INSTANCE "INVX1":"physical"
"A" : "reset"
"Y" : "pp_resetbar"

INSTANCE "INVX1":"physical"
"A" : "reset"
"Y" : "pp_resetbar"
```

and I want to change/replace the first two and delete the 3rd, 4th, ..., Nth

```
INSTANCE "INVX1":"physical"
"A" : "reset"
"Y" : "pp_resetbar_b"

INSTANCE "BUFX2":"physical"
"A" : "pp_resetbar_b"
"Y" : "pp_resetbar"
```

To be honest I don't even know where to start. I created a script to replace the Nth occurrence but doesn't seem work for this. See below. Any help will be more than appreciated.

```
awk -v search=$2 -v replace=$3 -v cnt=$4 '$0 ~ search{c++;if(c==cnt){sub(search,replace);}}1' "$file" > temp && mv temp "$file"
```

Comment: So ... is it the exact duplicate of these 4 lines that you want to remove?  That is, if there was an `INSTANCE "INVX2":"physical"`, but the rest was the same, you'd print it?  Also, are all repeated instances grouped together, or might a repeat show up later, after some other records that are supposed to be kept?  I think we need more details about where this data is coming from and what you plan to use it for; this isn't enough of an example to cover the scope of modification you've asked for.

Comment: The `INSTANCE "INVX1":"physical"` blocks are normally grouped but might not be for all files. What I'll like to have is a script that I can tell which occurrence to change, similar to the script I posted but for a multiline string.

Comment: I still don't think we have enough to go on.  I mean, we could do multi-line pattern detection with a series of `if` conditions in awk, setting state for future instances of the pattern, but this would seem to be a very localized solution.  What about converting your data into something more easily sorted and analyzed, then converting it back to the format you need for whatever application uses this data?

Comment: I'm under the assumption that the first code block is the input and the second should be the output.  Is that right?  If so, where did "pp_resetbar_b" and "BUFX2" come from?  That wasn't in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Untested but should be close:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS="\n\n" '
    { c = ++count[$0] }
    c == 1 { <replace some stuff> }
    c == 2 { <replace other stuff> }
    c <= 2
' file
```